# Access Jupyter notebook running on Docker container

Tags: python, docker, jupyter-notebook

I created a docker image with python libraries and Jupyter. 
I start the container with the option `-p 8888:8888`, to link ports between host and container. 
When I launch a Jupyter kernel inside the container, it is running on `localhost:8888` (and does not find a browser). I used the command `jupyter notebook`

But from my host, what is the IP address I have to use to work with Jupyter in host's browser ?

With the command `ifconfig`, I find `eth0`, `docker`, `wlan0`, `lo` ...

Thanks !

Comment: To launch the docker container I use `nvidia-docker`.

Comment: Did you check, if something is listening on localhost:8888? For example using netcat?

Comment: I tried in a browser localhost:8888, but not using netcat

Comment: Well you need to debug the situation. First, see if your container is actually running (start without -d, attach or simply run `docker ps`). Second, you need to check if your port is actually passed through to your host.

Comment: Hello
I'm sorry, I took 5 days off.

This solution works : 

Into the container : `jupyter notebook --ip 0.0.0.0 --no-browser`
Into a browser (ost) : `localhost:8888/tree`

Answer (score 106):

You need to run your notebook on `0.0.0.0`: `jupyter notebook -i 0.0.0.0`. Running on localhost make it available only from inside the container.

Comment: Docker : `docker run -it -p 8888:8888 image:version`  
Container :  `jupyter notebook --ip 0.0.0.0 --no-browser`  
Host : `localhost:8888/tree‌​`

Comment: @j-guillaumin Thank you very much! It just works by using command jupyter notebook --ip 0.0.0.0 --no-browser instead of jupyter notebook.

Comment: Now you have to add this flag : `--allow-root` ! 
It comes from a security issue from Jupyter. 
Or you can custom the configuration file to allow root (*.py in `~/.jupyter.`)

Comment: Use `--port XXXX` with `jupyter` in case you publish a different port with `docker run` than the jupyter default 8888. You also may need to include `--allow-root` with the jupyter call.

Comment: if your jupter image does not have the option to start with parameters , just use host networking for development; `docker run  --gpus all -it --network host tensorflow/tensorflow:latest-gpu-jupyter`

Comment: Thanks @AlexPunnen `--network host` with `-i 0.0.0.0` worked for me

Comment: May run at once on host side: `docker run -it -p 8888:8888 image:version jupyter notebook --ip 0.0.0.0 --no-browser --allow-root`

Answer (score 97):

Host machine: `docker run -it -p 8888:8888 image:version`

Inside the Container : `jupyter notebook --ip 0.0.0.0 --no-browser --allow-root`

Host machine access this url : `localhost:8888/tree‌​`

When you are logging in for the first time there will be a link displayed on the terminal to log on with a token.

Comment: If the host's port 8888 is occupied, we can use other ports, e.g., 8899.

Host machine: `docker run -it -p 8899:8888 image:version`

Host machine access this url : `localhost:8899/tree‌​`

Comment: Jupyter lab is also working like this: jupyter lab --ip 0.0.0.0 --no-browser --allow-root

Comment: On my side, one additional thing the jupyter start command also provide a base64 token I must pass to connect
http://127.0.0.1:8888/tree?token=<TOKEN_SEEN_ON_STARTUP>, then it worked

Answer (score 52):

The `docker run` command is mandatory to open a port for the container to allow the connection from a host browser, assigning the port to the docker container with -p, select your jupyter image from your `docker images`.

```
docker run -it -p 8888:8888 image:version
```

Inside the container launch the notebook assigning the port you opened:

```
jupyter notebook --ip 0.0.0.0 --port 8888 --no-browser --allow-root
```

Access the notebook through your desktops browser on http://localhost:8888
The notebook will prompt you for a token which was generated when you create the notebook.

Comment: is it using bind mount or volumn?  Or no storage is shared with the host

Comment: @LukAron Unless the `-v` option is specified for the docker run command, no storage will be shared with the host. To map a volume for sharing, something like `-v /path/to/host/source:/container/path/to/src` can be used. But be careful, that will hide anything the container may have at `/container/path/to/src`.

Comment: It's too bad the downvoter didn't give a reason why; this is almost verbatim the command I am now using successfully. The only differences are that I'm specifying the full path to jupyter, and I'm making it possible to choose a different port using an environment variable.

Comment: Hmm not working for me. Wish I knew what to check.

Answer (score 13):

To get the link to your Jupyter notebook server:

After your `docker run` command, a hyperlink should be automatically generated. It looks something like this: `http://localhost:8888/?token=f3a8354eb82c92f5a12399fe1835bf8f31275f917928c8d2 :: /home/jovyan/work`

If you want to get the link again later down the line, you can type `docker exec -it <docker_container_name> jupyter notebook list`.

Comment: `jupyter notebook list` doesn't work due to [this](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/2375) issue :(

Comment: Oh! For the IP, you can use the command `hostname -I` to get the IP of your remote server (if you're using a remote host). Then replace "localhost" in the URL with the IP.

Comment: If you specify `-it` to your initial `docker run` command, and you're running from within PyCharm Professional, you can just click the link in the `Attached Console` window. If you just run it from the shell, your shell may or may not let you click the link.

Answer (score 5):

The below is how I get it running on Windows 7 with docker toolbox.

If you are using docker toolbox, open up the Docker quickstart terminal, and note the IP here:

```
docker is configured to use the default machine with IP 192.168.99.100
For help getting started, check out the docs at https://docs.docker.com
```

Once you run the docker commands from the [tensorflow installation website](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/):

```
docker pull tensorflow/tensorflow                  # Download latest image
docker run -it -p 8888:8888 tensorflow/tensorflow  # Start a Jupyter notebook server
```

You will receive a message like this:

```
Copy/paste this URL into your browser when you connect for the first time,
to login with a token:
    http://127.0.0.1:8888/?token=d6e80acaf08e09853dc72f6b0f022b8225f94f
```

In the host, replace **127.0.0.1** with **192.168.99.100** and use the rest of that URL

Comment: Will it work if I want the Jupyter to run on port 5000?

Comment: @jeffrycopps yes, you just need to specify the port `-p <host port>:<container port>` correctly. For example, if you want to run it on the container at `5000`, but host at `8888`, use `-p 8888:5000`, and be sure to `--expose 5000`. Also, depending on your specific configuration, you may need to specify `-p 127.0.0.1:8888:5000` to access it from the host. (I realize it's been over a year since you asked that, but figured I'd help out anyone coming along who might have the same question.)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the command `jupyter notebook --allow-root  --ip[of your container]` or give access to all ip using option `--ip0.0.0.0`.

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative to building your own Docker image, you can also use the [ML Workspace](https://github.com/ml-tooling/ml-workspace) image. The ML Workspace is an open-source web IDE that combines Jupyter, VS Code, a Desktop GUI, and many other tools & libraries into one convenient Docker image. Deploying a single workspace instance is as simple as:

```
docker run -p 8080:8080 mltooling/ml-workspace:latest
```

All tools are accessible from the same port and integrated into the Jupyter UI. You can find further documentation [here](https://github.com/ml-tooling/ml-workspace).

Answer (score 1):

In the container you can run the following to make it available on your local machine (using your docker machine's ip address).

jupyter notebook --ip 0.0.0.0 --allow-root

You may not need to provide the --allow-root flag depending on your container's setup.

Answer (score 1):

```
docker run -i -t -p 8888:8888 continuumio/anaconda3 /bin/bash -c "/opt/conda/bin/conda install jupyter -y --quiet && mkdir /opt/notebooks && /opt/conda/bin/jupyter notebook --notebook-dir=/opt/notebooks --ip='*' --port=8888 --no-browser --allow-root"
```

i had to add --allow-root to the command and now its running

Answer (score 0):

The Makefile below encapsulates the previous answers and ensures that **jupyter** and **docker** agree on the port.  And if I just click/copy the link provided by jupyter, that solves port mismatch problems.

To use, just `make jupyter` or `make jupyter PORT=xxxx` from the proper folder. Then click the link in the jupyter output.

### Remote Containers

If your container is on a remote host (say an AWS EC2), then you'll also need to set up an ssh tunnel *with the correct port*. For example, on the *local* machine:

```sh
ssh -N -f -L localhost:8888:localhost:8888 username@remote-host
```

But at least that's only *one* place I can manually mismatch ports.

### Makefile

```
# Set your default jupyter port here. 
# Avoid 8888 if you run local notebooks on that!
PORT=8888
# Your app root in the container.
APP_DIR=/app
# The docker image to launch.  *** SET TO YOUR image:version! ***
APP_TAG=image:version

jupyter: ##
    ## Launch jupyter notebook from our container, mapping two folders
    ##    Local          Container       Notes
    ##    -----------------------------------------------------
    ##    ./data      -> /data           Put data here!
    ##    ./notebooks -> /notebooks      Find notebooks here!
    ##    -----------------------------------------------------
    ## Arg:  PORT - specify port [${PORT}]
    docker run \
        -p $(PORT):$(PORT) \
        -v $(PWD)/notebooks/:$(APP_DIR)/notebooks/ \
        -v $(PWD)/data:/data \
        $(APP_TAG) \
        jupyter notebook --ip 0.0.0.0 --port $(PORT) \
          --no-browser --allow-root
```

Answer (score 0):

Go in the Docker and check `cat /etc/jupyter/jupyter_notebook_config.py` :

- You should see / add this line :

`c.NotebookApp.allow_origin = 'https://colab.research.google.com'`