# Access Jupyter notebook running on Docker container on server

Tags: python, docker, jupyter-notebook

I have installed jupyter on a running container.

I'm unable to access the jupyter from my localhost.

I did:

```sh
    #Acess server
    ssh data@tmp-server-prod
    # on server
    docker ps
    f04ccccccc7        registry.gitlab.com/BNPworld/business-intelligence/jupyter_project:9ad9XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX8   "/bin/bash -c '/usr/"   7 weeks ago         Up 7 weeks                                    jupyter_project
    #    
    docker run -it -p 8888:8888 registry.gitlab.com/BNPworld/business-intelligence/jupyter_project:9ad9XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX8
    # access to container
    docker container exec -it f04ccccccc7 bash
    #inside container
    jupyter notebook --ip 0.0.0.0 --no-browser --allow-root
    **i got**
    http://127.0.0.1:8888/?token=16125997dXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX24cd5d99
```

when I copied to browser but it doesn't work.

Comment: Here `127.0.0.1` (or `localhost`) is the host from *inside* the container. When you paste it in your browser it targets your computer. You must use the hostname/IP of the machine running the container.

Comment: didn't got you. can you explain more please? @AymDev

Comment: `localhost` or the `127.0.0.1` IPv4 address mean "the current machine". Inside the container, it targets the container, but from your computer (or here your browser specifically), it targets your computer. As I can see, your container exposes the `8888` port but you are running your container from a remote server `tmp-server-prod`, meaning that the `8888` port of your container is mapped to its host's `8888` port. So from your local computer, in your browser, you should use the remote server IP or domain name, not `127.0.0.1`.

Comment: yes it's better thank you  @AymDev!! my ip server machine is: 192.186.16.16, so i did http://10.5.12.5:8888/?token=16125997dXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX24cd5d99 and it's still unreachable :/

Comment: I'm no expert in networking but I think the addresses you mentioned are from a private network, and are unreachable from your local computer. Search for your server's public IP and it should work. If you want to check if your container runs correctly, connect in SSH to your server and make an HTTP request to the local `8888` port: `curl http://127.0.0.1:8888/?token=16125997dXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX24cd5d99`

Comment: @AymDev got this error curl: (7) Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 8888: Connexion refused

Comment: It should work if executed from your remote server and the container is running with exposed port.

Comment: @AymDev How do I find out what port a container is running , maybe it is not the 8888 Have you an idea please??

Comment: It should be `8888` from what I read of your answer. You can use the [`docker port`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/port/) command to debug.

Comment: Yess i see, but the container was running before i was not the person who created, i was following this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38830610/access-jupyter-notebook-running-on-docker-container. by the way when i did **docker port jupyter_project** got nothing as output.

Comment: If you have no output I'd guess the container has been stopped. Does `docker ps` outputs anything right now ? That would explain why you can't access your app.

Comment: @AymDev the output of docker ps is                                                             f04ccccccc7 registry.gitlab.com/BNPworld/business-intelligence/jupyter_project:9ad9XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX8 "/bin/bash -c '/usr/" 7 weeks ago Up 7 weeks jupyter_project

Comment: `docker ps` usually display port mappings, it looks like there are none returned here. You said earlier that you were not the one who started the container. Maybe it has been started without port mapping ? Using Docker Compose would help here as you would have port mappings specified in a file and wouldn't worry about how someone else started the containers.

Comment: @AymDev Yes, i confirm that in dockerfile there is no expose and in gitlab-ci there is no mapping. what do you mean by **Using Docker Compose would help here as you would have port mappings specified in a file and wouldn't worry about how someone else started the containers.**  then how should i do to acces my jupyter?