# Why is there not a "global" link showing when starting a jupyter notebook inside a docker container

Tags: docker, jupyter-notebook, debian, remote-access

I want to use acces a jupter notebook which is running in a debian server using docker containers thru my local machine. The problem I face is that I expect a link with a token which I can insert in my browser on my local machine, but unfortunately this isn't the case.

When I start the jupyter notebook with the configs:

```
CMD ["python", "-m", "jupyterlab", "--port=8888", "--no-browser", "--ip=0.0.0.0", "--allow-root", "-NotebookApp.token=''", "--NotebookApp.password=''", "examples/notebooks"]
```

A link like this comes out  **http://<ip_adress>/lab**, but I expect something like this **http://<ip_adress>/lab/?token=**

Does anyone know how to fix this?

P.S. I've read and tried all the answers from this thread [Access Jupyter notebook running on Docker container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38830610/access-jupyter-notebook-running-on-docker-container)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not seeing a token because you've set `-NotebookApp.token=''`.

In combination with `-NotebookApp.password=''` you have completely disabled security (see [the docs](https://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/stable/security.html)). These means you can access JupyterLab at `http://localhost:8888` without requiring any password or token.

If this is not the behavior you want, don't explicitly disable the security features.