# How to run Jupiter notebook in a container locally?

Tags: python, docker, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

I can successfully run a `.py` file from within a Docker container.

However, I cannot run a Jupiter notebook from within a container as the container kernel is not selectable (I use VS Code). I have also tried to launch the notebook from the terminal with `jupyter notebook file.ipynb` (after having built the container and activated its environment), but that's not working.
What am I missing here?

**UPDATE**: If I run the container with `docker run -it --rm -t -d -p 8888:8888 -v ...`, the command `jupyter notebook` is working but I cannot activate the container environment (it does not find it). On the contrary, if  I run the container with `docker run -it --rm -t -p 8888:8888 -v` (i.e. skipping the `-d` option), the container environment is automatically and correctly set (i.e. I do not need `conda activate`), but I cannot launch the notebook as I get the message: `bash: jupyter: command not found`.

Comment: Are using a python virtual environment in the container? Using the `jupyter notebook` from within the virtual environment (in the container) should work just fine

Comment: Use VSCode `Remote Explorer` to connect to your container. Then you should be able to open, run, do anything you need as usual using the 'Explorer'.

Comment: The settings file allows you to specify which kernel to run by default. see https://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config.html

Comment: (There is also a typo in your command as pointed out by the correction of Pietro).

Comment: If I use ```jupyter notebook```, it says ```jupyter: command not found```. As for ```Remote Explorer```, the python interpreter is still not set to the one within the container, even if the folder has been attached to the container.

Comment: Can this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38830610/access-jupyter-notebook-running-on-docker-container) help?

Comment: Problem is: ```bash: jupyter: command not found```. And running ```conda install jupyter``` did not work.

Comment: I add an update on this in the main post