# opening Jupyter Lab in docker container

Tags: python, docker, localhost, jupyter-lab

recently started using docker and tried to crate a container with jupyter lab, so it could run on a local host.

Since I have been using anaconda before it seems like that localhost:8888 is already taken, so I have tried to use another avaliable port. `docker run -p 8080:8080 <image_name>' created a link which web page with token authentification which gives me no chance to enter. Also it used same port 8888. Is there any other port to use so that both, anaconda and docker work together without errors?

Answer (score 0):

[Have you tried this?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48986548/11555166)

TL;DR:

Run docker as

```
docker run -it -p 8888:8888 image:version
```

Then, inside your container, initialize Jupyter with:

```
jupyter notebook --ip 0.0.0.0 --no-browser --allow-root
```

Now you are supposedly able to access the notebook through your desktop browser on http://localhost:8888

Comment: I run in in detached mode then entered container and wrote your second command, but it opened same web page with token authenication, which doesn't want to proceed with token from link

Answer (score 0):

The `-p` option to docker run takes two ports. First is the port on the host that you want to connect to, and second is the port within the container that the service is running on.

Assuming jupyter is running on port `8888` inside the container, and you want to access it on `8080` on your localhost, the command you are looking for would be:

```
docker run -p 8080:8888 <image_name>
```

or to run it interactively and clean up after itself:

```
docker run -it --rm 8080:8888 <image_name>
```

Comment: Didn't work for me. Still accessing web page with token authentication