# Cannot access URL link to open Jupyter notebook outside the docker container

Tags: docker, jupyter-notebook, nvidia-jetson-nano

I have Ros2-galatic-Pytorch image which I got from DockerHub.

Here's what I am doing.

1. Connecting to my Nvidia Jetson Nano via ssh from my macbook
2. Running the Ros-Gelatonic-Pytorch container image and linking the Port of the host and the container. With this command `sudo docker run -it -p 8888:8888 dustynv/ros:galactic-pytorch-l4t-r32.6.1`
3. manually installing jupyter notebook on that container instance (temporary for testing)
4. *Issue* -> It says the Jupyter notebook is running but when I click on the link it refuses to connect.

I did checked out [this Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38830610/access-jupyter-notebook-running-on-docker-container) but It don't work on my case. Maybe because I am doing ssh with Jetson nano.

Here the URL:

````
[I 09:25:22.897 NotebookApp] Jupyter Notebook 6.4.10 is running at:
[I 09:25:22.897 NotebookApp] http://localhost:8888/?token=f73cd75df704164ec6043bcb54f3b3be2687134659a1a3cd
[I 09:25:22.897 NotebookApp]  or http://127.0.0.1:8888/?token=f73cd75df704164ec6043bcb54f3b3be2687134659a1a3cd
[I 09:25:22.897 NotebookApp] Use Control-C to stop this server and shut down all kernels (twice to skip confirmation).
[W 09:25:22.916 NotebookApp] No web browser found: could not locate runnable browser.
[C 09:25:22.916 NotebookApp]

 

To access the notebook, open this file in a browser:
    file:///root/.local/share/jupyter/runtime/nbserver-201-open.html
Or copy and paste one of these URLs:
    http://localhost:8888/?token=f73cd75df704164ec6043bcb54f3b3be2687134659a1a3cd
 or http://127.0.0.1:8888/?token=f73cd75df704164ec6043bcb54f3b3be2687134659a1a3cd ```



I tried checking if the ports is listening on the host. It does
I am not able to access the URL link even if I install a jupyter notebook image ( jupyter/mininmal-notebook) and run its instance


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TWei8.png

    Here are the port details to check for firewall on the remote server:```opentrons@opentrons-desktop:~$ sudo lsof -i :8888
    COMMAND     PID USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
    docker-pr 10745 root    4u  IPv4 271917      0t0  TCP *:8888 (LISTEN)``` 
    
    on my computer:
    ```COMMAND  PID USER   FD   TYPE             DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
    ssh     2117  jay    5u  IPv4 0xd3cbf2494a59da73      0t0  TCP localhost:ddi-tcp-1 (LISTEN)
    ssh     2117  jay    6u  IPv6 0xd3cbf24e1446ba8b      0t0  TCP localhost:ddi-tcp-1 (LISTEN)```
````

Comment: If the container is running on an external server, other than your macbook: please check the firewall rules of your server + server provider to ensure that this port is accessible.

Comment: Thanks @tjarbo I checked it already. It has access