# How do I load a Jupyter notebook in my browser running on a docker container on my machine with the same environment variables as the container?

Tags: docker, flask, docker-compose, jupyter-notebook, ipython

## Problem I am trying to solve

I want to use a Jupyter notebook hosted on my local docker container that I view in my browser, and in that notebook I want to access all the same environment variables I have access to when I run command-line `python` or `IPython` in my container. I want to access these env vars because in order for me to run and test my application python code in my flask app via Jupyter notebook, that application code uses env vars. Worth noting: my local docker container is running a flask app via `docker compose`.

## Solutions I've tried

### First Attempt - steps to reproduce:

There is a very similar answer to this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48986548/3290924). I do follow this, however, my `docker run` command fails because it does not recognize environment variables, and I cannot find my answer from that post. I have spent 45 minutes google searching. Here is what I do (for the sake of this example here, I will call the image name `my-server`).

First my docker container is booted up. I do this via `docker compose up -d` in a directory `workspace` with multiple services, one of which includes `my-server`. I will also highlight where the env variable files are (there are two). To make this more clear we have the directory structure:

```
workspace/docker-compose.yaml
workspace/.env
workspace/my-server/Dockerfile
workspace/my-server/.env
```

There are other services that live in `workpspace` each with their own `Dockerfile`s, for context, but likely unrelated to what we solve here.

Next within the running Docker container I am in a bash shell. I have installed `jupyter` via `pip install jupyter` and then I issue (now from the `/my-server` directory in the container):

```
jupyter notebook --ip 0.0.0.0 --port 8888 --no-browser --allow-root
```

This succeeds.

Then, outside the container, I run:

```
docker run -it -p 8888:8888 my-server
```

This is where I run into issues. It seems the `docker run` command boots up the app. In the Python code that runs (application code we have written that references env variables we've created), it tries to read those env variables and cannot read them and throws runtime errors.

To counteract this, I did try:

```
docker run --env-file .env --env-file my-server/.env -p 8888:8888 my-server
```

and it similarly cannot read env variables that were set in `workspace/.env` and `workspace/my-server/.env`.

So for this attempt, I cannot even visit `localhost:8888` in my browser because port mapping fails.

### Second Attempt - steps to reproduce:

This time I do not run anything inside the container first. Jupyter is not installed yet. So outside the container I run:

```
docker run -i -t -p 8888:8888 my-server /bin/bash -c "pip install jupyter && jupyter notebook --ip='*' --port=8888 --no-browser --allow-root"
```

Now I can visit `0.0.0.0:8888` in my browser. However, now I create a notebook, and proceed to import python symbols defined by our app in a notebook cell that I am normally able to import without error when I am in the container and I boot up `python`. In the process of importing I end up receiving runtime errors saying it cannot find env variables.

## Alternatives I have tried

An alternative I do successfully is install `flask-shell-ipython` in my container and run Python commands within that IPython that references symbols in my application, and this succeeds. In my container I install this tool via via `pip install flask-shell-ipython` and access it via `FLASK_APP=api flask shell`. (`api` is a directory in `my-server`). Why am I running into errors in Jupyter notebook but not IPython?

I would love insight on how to solve this, I feel like I am close. I prefer to use Jupyter notebook instead if IPython.