# Access Jupyter Notebook Server running in Docker Container - Invalid credentials

Tags: docker, jupyter-notebook

I created a container, no optional settings, based on the image jupyter/scipy-notebook.

The log looks like this:

```
2023-12-26 08:43:23     To access the server, open this file in a browser:
2023-12-26 08:43:23         file:///home/jovyan/.local/share/jupyter/runtime/jpserver-7-open.html
2023-12-26 08:43:23     Or copy and paste one of these URLs:
2023-12-26 08:43:23         http://a5a866303475:8888/lab?token=5ece185c7ca6ac368c40fa4abc89f6355cd168dc8b2919f2
2023-12-26 08:43:23         http://127.0.0.1:8888/lab?token=5ece185c7ca6ac368c40fa4abc89f6355cd168dc8b2919f2
```

I browsed to http://127.0.0.1:8888/lab?token=5ece185c7ca6ac368c40fa4abc89f6355cd168dc8b2919f2

and the Jupyter login page opened. I pasted the token into the text box and I got

```
Invalid credentials
```

I have studied this answer and it doesn't seem to help:
[Access Jupyter notebook running on Docker container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38830610/access-jupyter-notebook-running-on-docker-container)